# jQuery - search by attribute values and change all the values

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I have the following sort of HTML:

```
<tr>
    <td data-pk="-999">test1</td>
    <td data-pk="-999">test1</td>
    <td data-pk="-999">test2</td>
    <td data-pk="-999">test3</td>
    <td data-pk="-999"><a data-pk="-999">test4</a></td>
</tr>
```

I want to change all the -999's to 24 (say).

Can anyone suggest some clean and quick jQuery that recursively traverses the DOM (from the tr) and changes all the -999's?

Basically, I have a table where I add a new temporary row to my site's front-end. When the user saves this row, a new id (24 in this case) is generated. "-999" is a flag for my backend to tell it that a new entry is required in the database and that an id should be returned.

Comment: why use it on all `<td>` and not just put it once on `<tr>`? `  Also can use `data('pk')` as getter and `data('pk',24)` as setter

Comment: @charlietfl I know... The trouble is that each change in <td> is linked to an event (external class) that requires a data-pk attribute. In theory, it's duplication, but in practice, I don't want to modify someone else's code and want to keep everything managed via bower.io

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [**attr()**](https://api.jquery.com/attr/)

```js
$('[data-pk="-999"]').attr('data-pk', 24);
```

```css
[data-pk="24"] {
  color:green;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<tr>
    <td data-pk="-999">test1</td>
    <td data-pk="-999">test1</td>
    <td data-pk="-999">test2</td>
    <td data-pk="-999">test3</td>
    <td data-pk="-999"><a data-pk="-999">test4</a></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Hello, thank you so much for your very useful comment. This works perfectly! I did: `tr.find('[data-pk="-999"]').each(function(){
    $(this).data('pk',val);
  });`